# Win 8 freezing when using flash

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, crash, bsod

My computer crashes sometimes watching movies **OR** flash videos on the internet, sometimes a bluescreen appear for seconds before the crash.

I don't even know how to reproduce the problem.

I tried looking at the event viewer but I didn't manage to track the actual problem down.

What other things can I do to trace it?

Comment: It looks like you voted for this question to be closed as duplicate attaching your not unrelated link.

Comment: Question, can the same computer play games? how often is sometimes per say hours of viewing what crashes it? What is the video card your using, including model type (like some cards are pushed to higher clocks)?

Comment: @Shimmy: Why would you feel the need to throw accusations around like "You probably didn't read the post in first place."? Is this your way of asking for free support? We prefer a more friendly tone on [su], so that we can all enjoy our time spent on the site. Please be mindful of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to a faulty or out of date graphic driver (I have had this exact problem). Update your drivers. This is *often* achieved by a standard Windows Update. You may also need to update your chipset driver too.

Or, depending on the make of your card, visit the manufacturers website to ensure that it is supported on Windows 8 and that you have the latest version.

You can also prevent the restart of the machine on a [BSOD so you can read the message.](https://superuser.com/questions/226321/windows-xp-blue-screens-and-reboots-instantly-on-boot-up)